# How to split a string based on number of white space

Tags: java, string, split, delimiter

I am trying to achieve this using the String.split function in Java but doesn't seem to find an elegant solution. The number of blank space between each character or word is fixed.

```
String original = "H  E  L  L  O    W  O  R  L  D"

String finalWord = original.split();

System.out.println(finalWord);

HELLO WORLD
```

Basically, the number of white space between each alphabet is fixed e.g. 2 and the number of white space between word is also fixed e.g. 4.

How can I achieve that using Java?

**H**(space)(space)**E**(space)(space)**L**(space)(space)**L**(space)(space)**O**(space)(space)(space)(space)**W**(space)(space)**O**(space)(space)**R**(space)(space)**L**(space)(space)**D**

into

HELLO(space)WORLD

Hope it's understandable!

Comment: First, replace `4 spaces` by `single space`. Then replace `2 spaces` with `blank space`.

Comment: Posting sample code that doesn't compile (i.e. "final" cannot be a variable name, `split` needs an argument, etc.) indicates that you didn't try too hard to find the solution on your own.

Comment: Is the number of spaces fixed *for all inputs*, or is it one of the variable parameters of the system?

Comment: You have 5 spaces between HELLO and WOLD

Comment: Is *"using the String.split"* part of the requirements?

Comment: @kyger I try using original.split("\\s+); or original.split(" "); or original.replaceAll(" ",""); and they all didn't work. Thank you for your reminder! Will make sure I include my trials next time!

Comment: @kryger split is not a must but that is what I could think of by searching online! The number of space is fixed like 2 for alphabet, 4 for separate word.

Comment: @Indent oops my bad will make the adjustment now

Comment: `split`, as the name indicates, splits a string into parts, which are returned in an array, which is seemingly not what you want to do. It's always a good idea to head over to [the Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to see what a function does or find a function which does what you want (i.e. replace).

Comment: @Dukeling Thanks for your advice , split was required for my case since I need to store each character into an array for some computation :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
original.replaceAll("\\s{4,}", " ").replaceAll("\\s{2,}", "").trim()
```

The first will replace 4+ spaces with a space and the second will replace 2+ spaces with no spaces.

Answer (score 1):

So you don't need to split it and you can simply replace 2 spaces for 1 empty and you get HELLO(space)WORLD:

```
String original = "H  E  L  L  O     W  O  R  L  D";
String a = original.replaceAll("  ", "");
System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: How it works exactly? I thought it would have output no space but surprisingly it showed the correct result.

Comment: This works only because OP included *five* spaces in their question and everyone copy-pasted the code directly from there.

Comment: Oops I am sorry its 2 space and 4 space, I have made the necessary adjustment.

Comment: Yes, the first string had 5 spaces between HELLO and WORLD so my solutions works fine, but now, with  4 spaces between words I think that better solution is @ajc

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a regular expression to the split-separator to split on two-or-three spaces, resulting in leaving the four spaces intact:

```
String input = "H  E  L  L  O    W  O  R  L  D";

String[] parts = input.split("\\W{2,3}"); // [H, E, L, L, O, , W, O, R, L, D]
System.out.println(String.join("", parts)); // HELLO WORLD
```

Comment: You've put 5 spaces instead of 4 in `original`. If you use 4 spaces, as per OP's requirement, you get "HELLOWORLD".

Comment: @DodgyCodeException good catch, things like these cause space shuttles to crash. Adapted to the real requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Replace 4 Spaces by 1 space and then 2 space by nothing : 
http://rextester.com/LURGM31649

```
String original = "H  E  L  L  O    W  O  R  L  D";
original.replaceAll("    ", " ").replaceAll("  ", "");
```

Comment: @baao that's not necessarily Javascript. It might be Groovy ;-)

Comment: This code now has one issue and one flaw. Issue: you don't care about the `replaceAll` result (i.e. not assigned to anything). Flaw: there is no point in using `replaceAll` instead of `replace`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try tis.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    //BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    //String line =reader.readLine();
    String line = "H  E  L  L  O    W  O  R  L  D";
    String finalString;

    finalString = line.replaceAll("  ", "");
    finalString = finalString.replaceAll("    ", " ");
    System.out.println(finalString);

}
```

Comment: @cmy113 It was easy, don't forget to click on the top arrow, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If it is not a homework, you can try this with Java 8

```
String original = "H  E  L  L  O    W  O  R  L  D";
String str = Stream.of(original.split("\\s{4}"))
                   .map(x-> x.replaceAll("\\s{2}", ""))
                   .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
System.out.println(str);
```